# Get words count in PO file

Tags: translation, poedit, po

How to calculate a number of words in PO file? 

Poedit shows only lines count. 

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try pocount

```
pocount fi.po
```

```
fi.po
type              strings      words (source)    words (translation)
translated:      47 (100%)        137 (100%)             123
fuzzy:            0 (  0%)          0 (  0%)             n/a
untranslated:     0 (  0%)          0 (  0%)             n/a
Total:           47               137                    123

unreviewed:       47 (100%)        137 (100%)             123
```

Comment: In case you wonder, pocount is part of the translate-toolkit package. In debian-based you can do apt-get install translate-toolkit [EDIT: added installation note for debian distros]